# How bad would be next custom join implementation for NSThread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

Cause `NSThread` can't be joinable I tried next method, it seems works ok, but is still very bad solution or good enough?

```
// init thread
NSThread *mythread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runThread:) object: nil];

// start thread
mythread.start;

// JOIN NSThread custom implementation
// wait until thread will finish execution
if (mythread.isExecuting) {
    while(mythread.isExecuting) {
        sleep(0);
    }
} else if (!mythread.isCancelled && !mythread.isFinished) {
    while(!mythread.isExecuting) {
        sleep(0);
    }
    while(mythread.isExecuting) {
        sleep(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe using Grand Central Dispatch could be an alternative. This provides everything you could ever think of :-)

Comment: @AndreasOetjen `NSThread` just looks easier and it's similar to **Java** `Thread`, mb you could write some examples on the next question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148774/implementing-next-threading-solutions-in-swift-objective-c

Comment: I would suggest you take a look yourself; there are several tutorials regarding GCD, or maybe NSOperation. Ranking from low- to high level, there are posix threads and `NSThread` (which are quite basic), then GCD and highest: `NSOperation` (which itself is based upon GCD).

Comment: @AndreasOetjen for the first solution I got it how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49235104/7767664 now I need find out how to implement the second one

Comment: @AndreasOetjen for second one I fount this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/13033373/7767664 but it's ugly

Comment: I think you should do this with NSOperation, which has similar properties. By the way, your code does not seem to be thread-safe at all, so you will run into problems soon (especially with concurrent access of global/static variables).

Comment: @AndreasOetjen which code isn't safe?

Comment: The code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148774/implementing-next-threading-solutions-in-swift-objective-c/49235104#49235104

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I just found example with similar code and I don't think it can be written differently with `dispatch_group_t`

Comment: @AndreasOetjen of course if I want to access class variable from different threads I need to make sure that such variable is thread-safe for example Java has https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html

Comment: @AndreasOetjen anyway those two blocks will process different data (different variables), so it's just another question (my own problem how I would use my data), and I don't talking about it here, only about threads

Comment: @AndreasOetjen so `dispatch_group_async` or `dispatch_queue_async` doesn't have methods like isRunning, isAlive or isExecution, but `NSOperation` has?

Comment: You'll likely find more success by not trying to force Objective-C threading to act like Java threading.   Use GCD for your concurrency model in iOS and OS X and you're app will work much better with the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A live lock like this is a bad idea on an iPhone, because it eats battery and CPU without doing anything, even though calling sleep(0) might give it a little bit of rest.

You could use [NSCondition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscondition?language=objc) to implement joining. The idea is that the parent thread will wait on the NSCondition, and the worker thread would signal on that condition when it finishes:

```
- (void)main1 {
    // thread 1: start up
    _joinCond = [NSCondition new];
    [mythread start];

    // thread 1: join, i.e. wait until thread 2 finishes
    [_joinCond lock];
    [_joinCond wait];
    [_joinCond unlock];
}

- (void)main2 {
    // thread 2 (mythread):
    // ... work, work, work ...
    // now we're done, notify:
    [_joinCond lock];
    [_joinCond signal];
    [_joinCond unlock];
}
```

Comment: I decided to use GCD